# How to scrape dynamic hidden HTML field (__VIEWSTATE) value?

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am using Scrapy, Python to scrape a website http://www.gasunietransportservices.nl/en/dataport-pages/lng-terminals/nominations that will provide the data in an excel file after, but first i need to set up the filters.

I implemented the requests exactly in my code but realized in the FormRequest that the VIEWSTATE and the EVENTVALIDATION are dynamic, they change with every request. What i wanted to do is to scrape them so i can provide them in the next request.

Both fields are provided in the HTML code but hidden <[the __VIEWSTATE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CYrt.png) >. I tried to use Selenium but no useful results.

```
 start_urls = [

    'http://www.gasunietransportservices.nl/en/dataport-pages/lng-terminals/nominations',
    'http://dataport.gastransportservices.nl/default.aspx?ReportPath=%2fTransparency%2fNominationsPerNetworkpoint&ReportTitle=NominationsPerNetworkpoint&TransparencySegment=06',
]

def start_requests(self):

    yield Request(
        url=self.start_urls[0],
        callback=self.parse
    )

def parse(self, response):

    sel = Selector(response)
    #import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    view_state = sel.xpath('//input[@id="__VIEWSTATE"]/@value').extract()
    event_validation = sel.xpath('//input[@id="__EVENTVALIDATION"]/@value').extract()

    formdata = {
        'scriptManager': 'scriptManager|ReportViewerControl$ctl09$Reserved_AsyncLoadTarget',
        '__EVENTTARGET': 'ReportViewerControl$ctl09$Reserved_AsyncLoadTarget',
        '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
        '__VIEWSTATE': '{}'.format(view_state[0]),
        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': 'CA0B0334',
        '__EVENTVALIDATION': '{}'.format(event_validation[0]),
        'ReportViewerControl$ctl03$ctl00': '',
        'ReportViewerControl$ctl03$ctl01': '',
        'ReportViewerControl$ctl10': 'ltr',
        'ReportViewerControl$ctl11': 'standards',
        'ReportViewerControl$AsyncWait$HiddenCancelField': 'False',
        'ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl03$txtValue': 'LNG Terminals',
        'ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl05$txtValue': 'ROTTERDAM (GATE) - 301345',
        'ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl07$txtValue': '5-10-2015 0:00:00',
        'ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl09$ddValue': '1',
        'ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl11$txtValue': '6-10-2015 0:00:00',
        'ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl13$ddValue': '1',
        'ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl15$ddValue': '1',
        'ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl17$ddValue': '1',
        'ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl05$divDropDown$ctl01': 'on',
        'ReportViewerControl$ToggleParam$store': '',
        'ReportViewerControl$ToggleParam$collapse': 'false',
        'ReportViewerControl$ctl05$ctl00$CurrentPage': '',
        'ReportViewerControl$ctl08$ClientClickedId': '',
        'ReportViewerControl$ctl07$store': '',
        'ReportViewerControl$ctl07$collapse': 'false',
        'ReportViewerControl$ctl09$VisibilityState$ctl00': 'None',
        'ReportViewerControl$ctl09$ScrollPosition': '',
        'ReportViewerControl$ctl09$ReportControl$ctl02': '',
        'ReportViewerControl$ctl09$ReportControl$ctl03': '',
        'ReportViewerControl$ctl09$ReportControl$ctl04': '100',
        '__ASYNCPOST': 'true',
    }

    yield FormRequest(
        url=self.start_urls[1],
        formdata=formdata,
        callback=self.parse_filter,

    )

def parse_filter(self, response):
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

Comment: seems to me the form on page (real html) is generated with some *in browser js library (like ExtJS)*. 
Your python form to yield is good. Yet, have you checked its values with the real browser form submit requests?

Comment: @IgorSavinkin  Yes, i checked all the form fields many times with the real browser, it is all good, the only things that change with each request are '__VIEWSTATE' & '__EVENTVALIDATION' and that's what i am trying to extract from html code, i already checked they exists but Hidden